# How to dynamic change vue component props in js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

for ex:

```
<body>
<div id="app">
  <ro-weview id="wv" src="http://google.com"></ro-weview>
</div>

<script>
  (function () {
    Vue.component("ro-webview", {
      props: ["src"],
      template: `
<input type="text"  class="form-control" style="border-color: #ccc;outline: none; box-shadow: none !important; " :value="src"/>
<iframe :src="src"/>
</div>`
    })
  })()

  new Vue({el: "#app"})

  setVueProp("#wv", "src", "http://bing.com")
</script>

</body>
```

I hope implement #setVueProp to set ro-webview src, how to do it? I know use js get iframe can set it's src, but I hope setProp for ro-webview instance

Answer (score 0):

You can not do something like `setVueProp`, but you can always have a component with multiple props, but only pass some of the props based on your requirement.

If needed you can put validation on [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Prop-Validation), making few of the props mandatory while having other props as optional.

```
Vue.component('example', {
  props: {
    // basic type check (`null` means accept any type)
    propA: Number,
    // multiple possible types
    propB: [String, Number],
    // a required string
    propC: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    // a number with default value
    propD: {
      type: Number,
      default: 100
    },
    // object/array defaults should be returned from a
    // factory function
    propE: {
      type: Object,
      default: function () {
        return { message: 'hello' }
      }
    },
    // custom validator function
    propF: {
      validator: function (value) {
        return value > 10
      }
    }
  }
})
```

You dont need to pass all the props to this component, but only where `required` is true are the ones need to be passed always.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide who is responsible for changing that. Given that it's a property, I would say the parent should do it. You can add a `:src` data attribute to the parent and use that to change it.

Here's an example:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.1.8/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var webview = Vue.component("ro-weview", {
    props: ["src"],
    template: '<input type="text"  class="form-control" style="border-color: #ccc;outline: none; box-shadow: none !important; " :value="src"/><iframe :src="src"/></div>'
  })

  var myApp = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    template: '<div id="app"><ro-weview :src="src"></ro-weview></div>',
    data: function() {
      return {
        src: 'http://www.google.com'
      }
    },
    methods: {
      setSrc: function(src) {
        this.src = src
      }
    },
    components: {
      'RoWebview': webview
    }
  })

    myApp.setSrc('http://www.bing.com')
})
</script>
```

Comment: it's too terrible to define a component scope function in app scope

Comment: Not really, no :) The app is the parent for this case. If you want to change that from *outside* the component, this is one way of doing it. Otherwise you can just implement it in the component.

Answer (score -2):

I only write js for my own app only run in latest chrome, so i can use es6 syntax, so I think following code is easy to understand, def relative class to put component relative functions

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
  <ro-webview id="wv" src="https://google.com"></ro-webview>
</div>

<script>
  (function () {
    Vue.component("ro-webview", {
      props: ["src"],
      template: `<iframe :src="src" target="_blank" style="width:100%;"/>`,
      mounted: function () {
        var thiz = this
        $(document).on("ro-wemedia.setSrc", function (e, v) {
          thiz.$set("src", v)
        })
      }
    })
  })()

  class RoWebview {
    constructor(selector) {
      this.selector = selector
    }

    setSrc(v) {
      $(this.selector).attr("src", v)
    }
  }

  new Vue({el: "#app"})
  new RoWebview("#wv").setSrc("http://bing.com")
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use jQuery to change reactive properties. It will lead to a lot of problems later. See how the changes are propagated - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: @motanelu I doesn't change reactive properties, in my demo, I change iframe src

Comment: You're breaking the encapsulation of your component: the component exposes an interface, a set of props that are used in the parent's template and you should use those props to interact with the component.